# How to get resource in controller action?

Tags: zend-framework

How to get resource in controller action?
Resource db was initialized in application.ini.

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // I want db resource here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try and see if this works:

```
$this->getFrontController()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('db')
```

Comment: So was rightly:
$db = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('db');

Answer (score 1):

> **UPDATE** : While this solution works, it is **NOT** a recommended
>   practice. Please, read comment by
>   *@Brian M.* below.

You can use [Zend_Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html). Initialize the database connection in the bootstrap and store it in the registry:

```
// set up the database handler
// (...)
Zend_Registry::set('dbh', $dbh);
```

Then you can retireve it from anywhere else:

```
$dbh = Zend_Registry::get('dbh');
```

Comment: I don't think using the registry like this is a smart idea. ZF gives you a way to access resources, and relying on a global registry can be problematic. If you want easier access to resources, try using the injector approach here: http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/235-A-Simple-Resource-Injector-for-ZF-Action-Controllers.html

Answer (score 0):

In answer to [a similar question on Nabble](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/How-to-get-an-application-resource-inside-a-controller-action-tp662344p662345.html), Matthew Weier O'Phinney (Mr Zend Framework 1) suggests using this form:

```
$this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('db');
```

---

So, in the context of this question, it would be something like:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // db resource here
        $db = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('db'); 
    }
}
```